# Using Test.IsRunningTest(), Risks and use-cases

Tags: unit-test, pricebookentry, test-data-isolation

Through our testing coverage implementation on a project, we encountered some collisions on a trigger which assigns a Pricebook to a Product and our test data factory (uses "@test setup" tag => no possibility to use sellAllData).

The collision happens at the moment we check in the source code whether a standard PricebookEntry is set or not for the product and whether we need to create it.

The collision's cause is that the Product's standard Pricebook (isStandard = TRUE) query returns nothing when the trigger is called from the test class.

In order to differentiate the contexts, we used the function `Test.IsRunningTest()` in our source code to figure out whether we should query the product's standard PricebookEntry or retrieve its Id using `Test.getStandardPricebookId()`.

As `Test.IsRunningTest()` is usually used to bypass triggers in a testing context, I would like to know:

- Are there some limitations/performances issues/risks with using the `IsRunningTest` function in a non-testing (but tested) APEX class ?
- Why doesn't the query to retrieve the standard Pricebook (isStandard=TRUE) work in a testing context ? Isn't the `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` a shortcut to `SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE isStandard = TRUE` ?
- If using the `Test.IsRunningTest()` function in a non-testing APEX class to handle these collisions is really risky, what workaround would you suggest ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> Are there some limitations/performances issues/risks with using the
>   IsRunningTest function in a non-testing (but tested) APEX class ?

NO - in fact, the best practice way to fetch the `standardPriceBookId` is in fact to use some Util method that returns it, and such Util method relies on `isRunningTest()` and `Test.getStandardPricebookId()`

```
private static Pricebook2 stdPricebook;
//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  getStdPricebookId : as of V31, testmethods can locate std pricebook wo seeAlldata=true
//  ------------------------------------------------------
public static ID getStdPricebookId() {
  if (Test.isRunningTest())  return Test.getStandardPricebookId();
  return getStdPricebook().id;  
} 

//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  getStdPriceBook: Singleton
//  -------------------------------------------------------
public static Pricebook2    getStdPriceBook () {
    if (stdPriceBook == null) 
        stdPriceBook    = [select id, name from Pricebook2 where isStandard = true limit 1];
    return stdPriceBook;    
}
```

> Why doesn't the query to retrieve the standard Pricebook
>   (isStandard=TRUE) work in a testing context ? Isn't the
>   Test.getStandardPricebookId() a shortcut to SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2
>   WHERE isStandard = TRUE ?

Because Pricebook2 are not considered setup data when you run in `@isTest`. Pricebooks can be mocked (and should be). Except standard Pricebook can't be mocked so in V31, SFDC provided a way to get the ID of the standard Pricebook

Collisions, if they occur in testing, can be ameliorated by not running tests asynchronously - but I haven't seen this given the code above, YMVM

Comment: A synthetic answer that advises the use of a Design Pattern, thanks and chosen as best answer. :)